# Subscript size for formulas in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, packages, fontsize, subscripts, superscripts

I am creating a beamer presentation where I have a lot of formulas. Between the packages used I have `\usepackage{amsmath}` and the theme for the presentation is `\usetheme{Warsaw}`.

As it can be seen in the attached picture, the size of the sub(super)script is bigger than the normal writting.

**Anyone knows a set of basic packages in order to get the classical formulas, without these size changes?**

[image: Output of one of the formulas]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: That's not the default outcome from beamer (uses sans serif fonts). Please show us a MWE that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Please provide the MWE.